# HTML Table element using JS - Apparent Issue

Tags: javascript, html

Cheers, everybody!
I'm generating an HTML table dynamically using JS, and placing it into a 'div' element in another page. It's sort of OK, a few amendments, but I get the table output, better than i would expect.

Nevertheless, the problem is that my destination page where the 'div' element is placed, doesn't get updated, it stays blank like there was nothing there when in fact there should be, since i'm setting it, and otherwise where does the table come from in the page, right? Seems awkward to me. I see a table, but there's no correspondent html code for it in the page. 
Specially because i need to take a look in detail to fix the issues in my table layout.
Now, I'm pretty sure this is a very naive question, beginner's, and if I only knew it enough, I would understand what's going on, but at the moment, it's totally impossible for me to stop to take a deeper look at this, lots of stuff.

I really could use some contribution, like a fast and elucidative answer, sort of what do i do to view the table html, where is it 'hiding'? Preferentially. 
But as much important as it, a few 'read this' or 'read that', if you don't mind, because at this stage, You know, bump into an obstacle every two steps.
Anyway,thanks in advance! I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Where's your code hiding? Without the code it's hard to say anything.

Comment: Thanks! Well, that's  good question. I generate a table element html and then i use
<<document.getElementById('MyDIV').innerHTML=MyTable;>>
I get the table there, but the page source is blank. My 'div' is blank, there's no code for the table... isn't that amazing? 
Why is it even there, after all? But it is...
I don't understand much of the theoretical concepts of using 'innerhtml', how does it affect the page, but i guess the page should have a code, right?

Comment: Not seen in the page source? Most likely you haven't saved the file, the page source comes from a server. Use dev tools to access dynamic HTML and other resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page source only displays static content received from the server. To see the dynamic content added by your JS code you need to use the developer tools of the browser.

Easiest way to do this is to right click on the table and select 'Inspect Element' to see the generated HTML for your table.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I knew it was a dummy thing! Thanks everybody for Your attention!

Comment: @ITP: If the above answer solved your issue, it would be helpful if you can mark this as the answer to your question.